# how to fix Illuminate\Queue\Worker::daemon(): SSL_read on shutdown: No such file or directory (2) in laravel

Tags: laravel, queue

I have got the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K94TW.png)

The block of code which raises the error is :

```
CopiedLogfileToFtpServer::dispatch($file,$userID,$filename)->onQueue('Copy-Logfile_to_FTP-server')->delay(now()->addMinute(2));
```

and job class is:

```
public function handle()
    {
                $file=$this->file;
                $filename=$this->filename;
                $userID=$this->userID;
                $ftp_host = "172.26.10.197"; /* host */
                $ftp_user_name ='username'; /* username */
                $ftp_user_pass = '123456789'; /* password */  
                $remote_file = $filename;
                $connect_it = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_host);
                ftp_pasv($connect_it,true);

                /* Login to FTP */
                $login_result = ftp_login($connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
                $fileList=ftp_nlist($connect_it, '.');
                \Log::info($fileList);
                if (in_array("./" . $userID, ftp_nlist($connect_it, '.'))) {
                    \Log::info('True');

                    $d = ftp_put($connect_it, "./" . $userID . '/' . $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY);
                } else {
                    \Log::info('false');

                    ftp_mkdir($connect_it, $userID);

                    $d = ftp_put($connect_it, "./" . $userID . '/' . $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY);

 }
```

Error log :

```
        D:\SepandProject\laravel>php artisan queue:work --queue=Copy-Logfile_to_FTP-server
        [2020-07-28 18:55:59][61] Processing: App\Jobs\CopiedLogfileToFtpServer
        [2020-07-28 18:56:02][61] Processed:  App\Jobs\CopiedLogfileToFtpServer
        [2020-07-28 18:56:02][62] Processing: App\Jobs\CopiedLogfileToFtpServer
        [2020-07-28 18:56:03][62] Failed:     App\Jobs\CopiedLogfileToFtpServer
        [2020-07-28 18:56:03][63] Processing: App\Jobs\CopiedLogfileToFtpServer
        [2020-07-28 18:56:05][63] Failed:     App\Jobs\CopiedLogfileToFtpServer
           ErrorException 
    Illuminate\Queue\Worker::daemon(): SSL_read on shutdown: No such file or directory (2)
    [2020-07-28 18:56:03][62] Failed:     App\Jobs\CopiedLogfileToFtpServer
        [2020-07-28 18:56:03][63] Processing: App\Jobs\CopiedLogfileToFtpServer
        [2020-07-28 18:56:05][63] Failed:     App\Jobs\CopiedLogfileToFtpServer
        
           ErrorException
        
          Illuminate\Queue\Worker::daemon(): SSL_read on shutdown: No such file or directory (2)
        
          at D:\SepandProject\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php:132
            128|             // If the daemon should run (not in maintenance mode, etc.), then we can run
            129|             // fire off this job for processing. Otherwise, we will need to sleep the
            130|             // worker so no more jobs are processed until they should be processed.
            131|             if ($job) {
          > 132|                 $this->runJob($job, $connectionName, $options);
            133|             } else {
            134|                 $this->sleep($options->sleep);
            135|             }
            136|
        
          1   D:\SepandProject\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php:132
              Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Illuminate\Queue\Worker::daemon(): SSL_read on shutdown: No such file or directory (2)", "D:\S
        epandProject\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php", ["database", "Copy-Logfile_to_FTP-server", Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions),
        Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob)])
        
          2   D:\SepandProject\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php:112
              Illuminate\Queue\Worker::daemon("database", "Copy-Logfile_to_FTP-server", Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
```

**this code without Queue well working**

Comment: Include your error in text instead of an image

Comment: Ok ... post edited